# Does a hidden input field affect SEO?

Tags: html, seo

If I have hidden input fields in a form, can I throw them around anywhere or will SEO 'punish' me for that?

examples:

```
...
<td>text</td>
<input type='hidden' />
<td>more text</td>
....
<td>text<input type='hidden' /></td>
<td>more text</td>
....
```

.. and not just anywhere in a table but anywhere in the page, does it matter where you put it if it's hidden?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google recommended that your code must be hidden but website content not hidden for website visitor. Example If u r website open than visitor must be seen your content.

Answer (score 1):

**Not in a form no.**

Google knows and expects people to use hidden input fields in many forms!

Comment: Besides, input elements do not even have to be inside a `<form>` tag to be submitted. Setting the `form` attribute on an element is also sufficient.

Comment: @RobW This will only be for HTML5. And probably won't work in IE

Comment: @yunzen All major browsers and IE10+ See [compatibility table](http://wufoo.com/html5/#attributes) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input#compat-desktop). My point is not whether it's wise to use the `form` attribute or not, but that a hidden inout element outside a form is not "suspicious by definition".

Comment: If not supported in IE9 then it renders fairly useless unfortunately. And I think you should have the HTML4 DOCTYPE to let this work.